# URL Rewrite of Location is causing an Object Moved to here link to appear on site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, pci-compliance

I have an MVC site  on IIS 8.0 I recently ran a security scan and failed saying that my internal IP address is being set on the HTTP response header. To mitigate this issue I installed URL rewrite and created an Outbound rule to replace the variable name RESPONSE_Location using wild cards and replacing it with an empty string. Doing this is causing an object moved link to appear when i access the site or click on any of the links. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your URL Rewrite rule's `redirectType` set to? Is it set to `Temporary`, by any chance?

Comment: im not sure i know where to find that setting.. if it is in the web config file i didnt add anything there. I made the changes in IIS outbound rules. I think I got the issue fixed. I went to IIS Under ConfigurationEditor>System.WebServer>ServerRuntime and added the website name under alternateHostname... I'm not sure what fixed the vulnerability or the Object moved to here problem.. but both seem to have been resolved. I wish i knew what it was lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the issue fixed. I went to IIS Under ConfigurationEditor>System.WebServer>ServerRuntime and added the website name under alternateHostname... I'm not sure what fixed the vulnerability or the Object moved to here problem.. but both seem to have been resolved. I wish i knew what it was lo